# Not able to see Uploaded and Activated Custom template while creating new site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-template

I have uploaded and activated Template (.wsp file) in sharepoint 2013.
While creating a new sharepoint site, the uploaded and activated template is not listed in "Custom" list. There is no "Page layouts and site templates" Option under The Look and Feel Section in SharePoint Site Settings.

Please help me to create Site in Sharepoint 2013 with my activated template.